# Standalone Raspberry Pi embedded system

Tags: embedded, driver

The Raspberry Pi embedded system is a standalone system it features a ARM processor and many peripheral devices, USB, LCD, Wifi adaptor ....etc

But I am puzzle on that.

For PC, when you installed a Wifi adaptor, you have install the driver too with accompanying CD.

But on the Raspberry embedded system, where, how  to install driver?  Without driver how does Wifi adaptor work?

It's puzzling.

Comment: Your assertion on the necessity of drivers is only true for some operating systems, like the Windows family.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato,   even in Linux you still need kernel module or driver to operate the adaptor hardware.   And kernel module is vendor specific.

Comment: my point is: I'm currently writing from a PC running a Linux distro, and I never had to "install from a CD". Of course you need some way of handling devices connected through various means, but different operating systems have different ways of dealing with this problem (BTW, be warned that "vendor" in terms of third-party devices might not mean the name on the box, but rather e.g. on the main chip). Also, the various operating systems available for the Pi are not strictly "embedded" - one reason is that they're pretty much interchangeable, it's up to you what you load on the SD card.

Comment: Linux generally has support for considerably more hardware than windows does, at the same time the newer the hardware and more secret the specs the less likely that hardware will have linux support.  but in general if it is going to work on linux it is usually not hard to enable it by clicking somewhere or adding a line in a config file or running a command to start the kernel driver that is currently not being used.  Raspberry pi and embedded have little to do with this the question is really is there a linux driver for your device or not and what kernel do you need for that

Comment: The de-facto Raspbian Linux distribution includes WiFi support for common chipsets. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7866/how-to-set-up-wifi-with-raspbian-wheezy and http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters. Other than that this question is in the wrong StackExchange.

Comment: @dwelch - it would be more accurate to say that Linux distributions tend to *ship with* drivers for many types of hardware where windows relies on vendor distribution of drivers... probably because historically vendors did not bother to provide Linux drivers for their hardware, so filling the gap for common peripherals was a major requirement for usability.  Overall, windows still leads on the likelihood of driver being available from someone for some version, but the new OS vs legacy peripheral problem can be more intractable than with Linux where porting is at least theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which operating system you install on your Raspberry Pi, support for the hardware is normally precompiled into the kernel or are included as kernel modules. There is normally no location to add in drivers - Linux works differently from windows

Comment: So, the distributed OS for raspberry pi already included All the drivers inside?  And they can only work with a specific vendor's  Wifi adaptor because the driver is vendor specific?

Comment: Here are some lists of tested wifi adapters: 
http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters
http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-44703/l/raspberry-pi-wifi-adapter-testing

Basically, there is only very specific wifi hardware that works with linux at this time

Comment: It is most definitely possible to add drivers to Linux.